# mongodb hacer una búsqueda que coincida con el array

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Necesito hacer una consulta en la que encuentre a los usuarios que coincidan
con los elementos de un array en el campo tag, que también es un array

```
const arr = ['uno','dos','tres']
const users = await User.find({ tag: { $in: arr } }).limit(10);
```

*¿Como hago para mostrar a los usuarios que al menos coincidan en **al menos 3 elementos**?*

Comment: ¿Tienes permitido usar `node.js` para obtener el resultado o es necesario hacer toda la consulta con `mongoDB`? saludos

Comment: si lo tengo permitido, pero no se si había alguna opción en mondodb. @g.4

Comment: Encontré una forma, espero te funcione, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Con el operador `$in`, se regresan los documentos donde al menos un valor del query `arr` este presente en el campo `tag`.

Se puede usar el [operador `$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/), para obtener mas precisión en el resultado.

El operador `$all` regresará ls documentos donde **todos** los valores especifícados en el query `arr`, esten presentes en el array del campo `tag`:

```
const arr = ['uno','dos','tres']
const users = await User.find({ tag: { $all: arr } }).limit(10).toArray();
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo de la pregunta pide **al menos 3**, por lo que se puede intuir que podría poner un arreglo de 15 pero pedir que sólo coincidan 3

Comment: Es verdad, vamos a esperar el feedback de @digital and ole y ver si hay que complementar la pieza de código, saludos

Comment: @EduardoJiménez tiene razón, encontré una forma en la que puedo hacerlo  con aggregate   
   const users = await User.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: { $gte: [{ $size: { $setIntersection: ["$tag", arr] } }, 4] },
        },
      },

      {
        $limit: 5,
      },
    ]);

Comment: @digitalandolé sería bueno que lo publicaras como respuesta