# Mongoose: Obtener los datos de un objeto dentro de un array anidado con $elemMatch(?)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Dentro de este modelo de un registro en mi BBDD MongoDB tengo esto:

```
                 {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "63a47cebfafc3b36b9defea1"
                    },
                    "team_name": "Atlético de Madrid Femenino",
                    "formal_name": "Atlético de Madrid",
                    "location_city": "Madrid",
                    "year_foundation": "2001",
                    "slug": "atletico_madrid",
                    "players": [{
                        "name": "Lola Gallardo",
                        "slug": "lola_gallardo",
                        "birthday": "1993-06-10",
                        "position": "Goalkeeper",
                        "position_abbreviate": "GK",
                        "nationality": "Spain",
                        "dorsal": "13",
                        "club": "Atlético de Madrid",
                        "_id": {
                            "$oid": "63a47cebfafc3b36b9defea2"
                        }
                    }
                    }],
                    "__v": 0,
                    "createdAt": {
                        "$date": "2022-12-22T15:51:07.117Z"
                    },
                    "updatedAt": {
                        "$date": "2022-12-22T15:51:07.117Z"
                    }
                }
```

Y en la función que recibe el parámetro **Slug** (ahora hardcodeado), tengo lo siguiente:

```
       export const getPlayerBySlug = async (slug: string): Promise<ITeams | null> => {
            await db.connect();
            
       //intento obtener los datos dentro del player del slug que envio
       //-------------------------------------------------------------
           const player = await Teams.find({
              players: {
                $elemMatch: {
                  slug: "lola_gallardo",
                },
              },
            }).lean();
       //-------------------------------------------------------------
            await db.disconnect();
            if (!player) {
              return null;
            }
            return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(player));
          };
```

Pruebo con **$elemMatch** y me halla todo el registro entero, pero solamente quiero obtener los datos de ***"lola_gallardo"*** que figuran en el objeto dento del array **"players**". Cómo puedo hacer find dentro del array?

Comment: Bueno y en la estructura `players` tienes mas registros(objetos) ademas de `Lola Gallardo`, ¿cierto?

Comment: claro, es un array

Comment: Puede que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/482019/101408) sea de ayuda